# Resizing font based on screen width

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me with JavaScript code that resizes a font in a div if the screen width is lower than 1100px

```
if (window.screen.width <= 1100) {
  var item = document.getElementById("div1");
  item.style.fontSize = "25px";
  item.innerHTML = "String";
}
```

This is what I have so far. Can someone help me with what to do next?

Comment: That looks reasonable to me — what's the problem? Please edit your question to let us know exactly what you don't understand or what you would like to do that isn't currently happening.

Comment: i didnt add event on resize ... tnx :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me in JS Fiddle.  Perhaps you are not specifying the correct id for your div or something like that.

http://jsfiddle.net/trott/GqFPY/

If you are hoping the code will be triggered on a browser resize, you will need to bind it to an event.  (See Michael's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bind the action to the `window.onresize` event:

```
var resizeFonts = function() {
  var item = document.getElementById("div1");
  if (window.screen.width <= 1100) {
      item.style.fontSize = "25px";
      item.innerHTML = "String";
  }
  // Otherwise set a larger font
  else item.style.fontSize = "30px";
};

window.onload = resizeFonts;
window.onresize = resizeFonts;
```

Comment: i puted ur code inside the <script> tags but still no change on my div1 tag when i connect to my site with a lower resolution.

Comment: @triputap See change above. If you want it to change on page load as well as resize, assign the function to `window.onload` and `window.onresize`

Answer (score 0):

I have an ***OLD*** blog in which I posted about changing the font size, but it was made to show how to use jQueryUI slider. Maybe you can use some of the logic there to create your own solution:

http://weblogs.asp.net/thiagosantos/archive/2009/03/21/my-first-time-with-jquery-ui.aspx